# Working with stack - override onBackPressed

Tags: java, android, android-activity, stack

I have this code in my android app and im trying to override the onbackPressed function so if there is item in the stack to be shown, else the current activity to be closed, but somehow my stack doesnt remove the item on top although I'm doing `pop()`.What can here be the issue?

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.v("--", backStack.size() + "BS");
        if (backStack.size() == 0) {
            finish();
        } else {
            position = backStack.pop();
            Log.v("--", "BAck " + position);
            webView.clearView();
            String html = head + mustReads.get(position).getBody() + footer;
            backStack.push(position);
            Log.v("--", "LITLIB html: " + html);

            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
            getActionBar().setTitle(mustReads.get(position).getTitle());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your else clause will never be called because you call `push()` immediately after `pop()`. So your backStack size will always be greater than 0.

Comment: @Nachi thanks for your help. That was the solution. After an hour of searching for the issue... I didnt saw the `backStack.push(position)` code... Submit your answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your else clause will never be called because you call push() immediately after pop(). So your backStack size will always be greater than 0.